# What is the Java BitSet size after growing, shrinking and cloning its value?

Tags: java, memory-management, clone, bitset

Let be `bs1` a BitSet in Java.
The first bit is set `bs1.set(0)`, then its `size` and `length` are 64 and 1 respectively.
The 65th bit is set `bs1.set(64)`, then its `size` and `length` are 128 and 65 respectively.

Now, if I clear its 65th bit `bs1.clear(64)`, its `length` go back to 1, but what happen with its size?
What happen if I clone the bitset? is the new one's size default?

Answer (score 0):

Less words and more code, here the experiment that in my opinion answers the question:

```
    import java.util.BitSet;

public class BitSetExperiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitSet bs0=new BitSet();
        BitSet bs1;
        System.out.println("created:\tLength,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());
        bs0.set(15);
        System.out.println("set(15):\tLength,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());
        bs0.set(63);
        System.out.println("set(63):\tLength,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());
        bs0.set(86);
        System.out.println("set(86):\tLength,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());
        bs0.clear(86);
        System.out.println("clear(86):\tLength,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());
        bs0.clear(63);
        System.out.println("clear(63):\tLength,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());

        System.out.println("Cloning to bs1...\n");
        bs1=(BitSet)bs0.clone();
        System.out.println("Length,Size bs0: "+bs0.length()+" , "+bs0.size());
        System.out.println("Length,Size bs1: "+bs1.length()+" , "+bs1.size());
    }
}
```

The output:

```
created:    Length,Size bs0: 0 , 64
set(15):    Length,Size bs0: 16 , 64
set(63):    Length,Size bs0: 64 , 64
set(86):    Length,Size bs0: 87 , 128
clear(86):  Length,Size bs0: 64 , 128
clear(63):  Length,Size bs0: 16 , 128
Cloning to bs1...

Length,Size bs0: 16 , 64
Length,Size bs1: 16 , 64
```

Looking at the output, I found two things:

1. When you clear the more significant bits the BitSet DOES NOT trim its size, but maybe it is done using another mechanisms more sophisticated as @Boris the Spider suggest in his comment.
2. When you clone a BitSet, the original AND ALSO the clone are represented in the smallest possible allocation (in factors of 64 bits)

Comment: If a `BitSet` trimmed its size when you flipped a bit at the boundary, you would have degenerate performance. If the `BitSet` were to trim its size automatically, it would likely happen according to [best practice](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/aads/Algorithms/Array_resizing/) - which is a little more complex than your tests suggest.

Comment: Completely agree, it is very probable that Java actually trim the bitset but not right after clear the space. I will put that possibility in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer could depend on the implementation.  The following information was gleaned by reading the Java 11 source code.

The only API method that is specified to shrink a `BitSet` is `trimToSize()`.

Most (mutating) API methods *may* increase its size, but won't ever reduce it.

The exception to this are `clone()` and the (private) `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that are used for Java object serialization.  The behavior of these methods depend on a private field called `sizeIsSticky` which in turn depends on the previous history of the object.

If the `BitSet` is created with a capacity, it has a sticky size.  The size will stay stick unless the `BitSet` grows beyond its capacity.

- When you clone a `BitSet` with a sticky size, the clone object has the same size and the size is also sticky.
- When you clone a `BitSet` with a non-sticky size, the object is ffirst trimmed and then the clone is creates.  The clone's size will be non-sticky.
- When you serialize a `BitSet` with a sticky size, the serialized form preserves the size.
- When you serialize `BitSet` with a non-sticky size, the `BitSet` is trimmed before serializing.
- When you deserialize a `BitSet` from its serial form, the size is the same as for the serial form, and the stickyness is set heuristically.

The trimming that happens in `clone()` and `writeObject` when the size is non-sticky is a bit surprising, but that is what the (Java 11) code does.  The behavior is partly explained by the comment on the `sizeIsSticky` field.

```
/**
 * Whether the size of "words" is user-specified.  If so, we assume
 * the user knows what he's doing and try harder to preserve it.
 */
private transient boolean sizeIsSticky = false;
```